# In Dual Slider HTML component, click inside first element is not recognized in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular7

I am trying to build a Dual Step Slider using HTML and CSS alone without any JQuery. It is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla, But in IE11, it is not registering the click inside first input element.
I designed the slider by using position:absolute and made two html input sliders on top of each other. In IE, i could click and drag on Second Input Elemenr only.

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  //height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  //background: #f3f3f3;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.slider input {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 25%;
  top: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  outline: none;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;

}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  //border: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #3972D6;
  margin-top: -4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: 2px solid #cdcdcd;

  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 0;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ea4550;

  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.slider input::-moz-range-track {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 0;
}

.slider input:last-of-type::-moz-range-track {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: none transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.slider input[type="range"]::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}

.flex-next {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.dual-slider-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.dual-slider-text-left {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 8px;

  .text-style {
    color: #303030;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .text2 {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.dual-slider-text-right {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 8px;

  .text-style {
    color: #303030;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .text2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

//Internet Explorer Support
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;

  /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
  background: transparent;

  /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 6px 0;

  /*remove default tick marks*/
  color: transparent;
}

#lower::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#lower::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#higher::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#higher::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  //border: none;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #3972D6;
  //cursor: hand;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:8px" class="col-12 row m-0">
  <div class="dual-slider-text-left col-2 p-0">
    <div class="text-style">
      {{minValue}}
    </div>
    <div class="text2">{{minValueText}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 p-0">
    <div class="dual-slider-container">
      <input (click)="getSliderOneValue($event)" type="range" min="{{minValue}}" max="{{maxValue}}" step="1"
             value="{{sliderOneValue}}"
             class="slider" [disabled]="disabled"  [ngClass]="{'pointer' : !disabled}"
             id="lower">
    </div>
    <div class="dual-slider-container">
      <input (click)="getSliderTwoValue($event)" type="range" min="{{minValue}}" max="{{maxValue}}" step="1"
             value="{{sliderTwoValue}}"
             class="slider" [disabled]="disabled" [ngClass]="{'pointer' : !disabled}"
             id="higher">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dual-slider-text-right col-2 p-0">
    <div class="text-style">{{maxValue}}</div>
    <div class="text2">{{maxValueText}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In IE the second element is above the first one, hence it is completly hidden. You can check this by applying unique background colours to both elements.

Comment: But that would make it look awkward right.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can only reach the second slider if they're lapped in IE. You could use two slides side by side as a workaround. I make a demo and you could refer to it.

```css
body {
    min-height: 100px;
}
div {
    display: flex;
}
input {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
output {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="a" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
    <input id="b" type="range" min="11" max="20" value="20" />
</div>
<output></output>
```

Comment: Actually i need two slider in a single track like a two way slider. Is there any other way for that ???

Comment: I find [a sample](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) just like what you said--a two way slider, but it uses jquery. So it might doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Yeah Thanks, as you said i dont want to use jquery.